# Multiple List definition in a list template

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, list-template

I use Sharepoint Foundation 2010, and I'm working with a set of .stp's.

Now I have the requirement to create a list with a lookup field.
I also want to create this lookup list at the same time with the list above.

So is it possible to create two lists within one list temlate?
Or ist that only possible with a web/site template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the two lists together by using a Feature and including both list definitions/instances into this feature

Comment: But with a feature the user can't create an instance by itself or is that possible?

Comment: With a feature, you basically make your list definitions available. Then you can create an instance as the feature is activated or leave the creation to the users

Comment: Ah cool thx for the hint :)